# Слить 2 массива в новый по общему значению

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Помогите пожалуйста стиль 2 массива массивов:
Имеется 2 массива:

```
array:19 [▼    
   0 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "Арендатор"
        1 => "Возвраты<br>(РУБ, ВКЛ. НДС)"
        2 => "Возвраты<br>(ШТ.)"   
   ] 
   1 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "one"
        1 => "-25 900,00"
        2 => -7.0 
   ]
   2 => array:3 [▼
         0 => "two"
        1 => "-22 498,00"
        2 => -2.0   
   ] 
]
```

и второй массив

```
array:25 [▼
   0 => array:10 [▼
     0 => "Арендатор"
     1 => "Продажи<br><span>(руб, вкл. ндс)</span>"
     2 => "Продажи<br><span>(шт.)</span>"
     3 => "Возвраты<br><span>(руб, вкл. ндс)</span>"
     4 => "Возвраты<br><span>(шт.)</span>"
     5 => "Продажи<br>с учетом возвратов<br><span>(руб, вкл. ндс)</span>"
     6 => "Продажи<br>с учетом возвратов<br><span>(шт.)"
     7 => "Ср. ст-ть товара<br><span>(руб, вкл. ндс)"
     8 => "Кол-во чеков<br><span>(шт.)</span>"
     9 => "Средний чек<br><span>(руб, вкл. ндс)</span>"
   ]
   1 => array:10 [▼
     0 => "<a href="/dashboard?date_start=2018-02-01&date_end=2018-02-23&as_user=two">two</a>"
     1 => ""
     2 => ""
     3 => ""
     4 => ""
     5 => "526 077,00"
     6 => 270.0
     7 => "1 948,43"
     8 => 171
     9 => "3 076,47"
   ]
   2 => array:10 [▼
     0 => "<a href="/dashboard?date_start=2018-02-01&date_end=2018-02-23&as_user=one">one</a>"
     1 => ""
     2 => ""
     3 => ""
     4 => ""
     5 => "13 340,00"
     6 => 10.0
     7 => "1 334,00"
     8 => 10
     9 => "1 334,00"
   ]
```

Мне необходимо во второй массив в 3 и 4 строку записывать данные из 1 массива (1 и 2 строка соответственно), при условии, что имя во втором (0-строка, та часть, которая заключена в `<a></a>`) соответствует имени в первом массиве (так же нулевая строка)

Я понимаю, что нужно создать новый массив и в цикле прогонять оба массива и писать в новый, но на деле одни ошибки вылетают.

```
 $merge = [];
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['sells']); $i++) {
   $merge[$i] = $array['sells'][$i]; 
   if(in_array(substr(strstr($merge[$i][0], '>'), 1, -4),$array['refunds'][$i][0] )){
     $merge[$i][4] = $array['refunds'][$i][2];
   }
 }
```

Я сделал так, но **$array['refunds'][$i][0]** выдает строки, а не массив Не могу понять, так вставить код.

Comment: Доброе утро. Так покажите свой код и ошибки покажите.

Comment: @peter
[meta]
$merge = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['sells']); $i++) {
            $merge[$i] = $array['sells'][$i];
            if(in_array(substr(strstr($merge[$i][0], '>'), 1, -4),$array['refunds'][$i][0] )){
                $merge[$i][4] = $array['refunds'][$i][2];
            } 
        }
[meta]
Я сделал так, но $array['refunds'][$i][0] выдает строки, а не массив

Не могу понять, так вставить код :/

Answer (score 0):

возьмите первый массив `$first`, извлеките значения 0-го столбца значения которого вам надо проверять на совпадение. Затем создайте новый массив, где эти 0-значения станут ключами.

```
   $keys = array_column($first, 0);
   $first = array_combine($keys, $first);
```

далее проходите по второму массиву и проверяйте нулевое значение. Если там нужный вам `<a>`, то извлеките значение, и проверьте есть ли он в первом. Если есть, то замените что надо

```
foreach($second as &$v){
   if(preg_match("/.*>(.*?)<\/a>/", $v[0], $matches)){
      $k = $matches[1];
       if(isset($first[$k]){
           $v[3] = $first[$k][1];
           $v[4] = $first[$k][2];
       }
   }
}
```

вероятно, как то так. (*код примерный, не проверялся*)

Comment: А не проще ли, сделать `strip_tags` ? За место регулярки.

Comment: @And если бы я был уверен, что там может располагаться только тэг `<a>` и ничего кроме, то так бы и было. Однако, в первом элементе просто текст - его проверять не надо, я так понял.

Comment: @Vladislav, избегайте кода в комментариях, читать не возможно. Дополняйте свой вопрос. Чтобы сразу было видно, что пробовали и как пытались, а вообще бы, нормальный массив рабочий, а дамп не нужен, просто не хочется переписывать в ручную.

Comment: Можно и `stripos($str, '<a')` для поиска юзнуть. К тому-же явно видно ссылку.

Comment: $merge = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['sells']); $i++) {
            $merge[$i] = $array['sells'][$i];
            if(in_array(substr(strstr($merge[$i][0], '>'), 1, -4),$array['refunds'][$i][0] )){
                $merge[$i][4] = $array['refunds'][$i][2];
            } 
        }

я уже измучился, у меня не вставляется как код. Проблема в $array['refunds'][$i][0]

Comment: @Vladislav, повторюсь, не надо писать код в комменты, да и не хочу переписывать массивы в рабочий вид.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_user = [];
            foreach ($array['refunds'] as $user) {
                $array_user[$user[0]] = array($user[1],$user[2]);
            };

            foreach ($array['sells'] as $key=> $user) {
                if(isset($array_user[substr(strstr($user[0], '>'), 1, -4)])) {
                $array['sells'][$key][1] = number_format((float)str_replace(" ", "", $array_user[substr(strstr($user[0], '>'), 1, -4)][0])*(-1) + (float)str_replace(" ", "", $array['sells'][$key][5]), 2, ',', ' ');
                $array['sells'][$key][2] = (intval($array_user[substr(strstr($user[0], '>'), 1, -4)][1]) - intval($array['sells'][$key][6]))*(-1);
                $array['sells'][$key][3] = $array_user[substr(strstr($user[0], '>'), 1, -4)][0];
                $array['sells'][$key][4] = $array_user[substr(strstr($user[0], '>'), 1, -4)][1];
                }
            }
```